# AntD | Input.Search - Input disabled but keep the search button enabled

Tags: reactjs, search, input, antd

I use [Input.Search](https://ant.design/components/input/#Input.Search). The `disabled` prop makes both the input & the button disabled. Here I want to keep the button enabled while the input is disabled.

Is there solution?

```
<Search
  enterButton
  placeholder="ID"
  // disabled
  onSearch={() => console.log('search')}
/>
```

Comment: Disable the input but the search button should be clickable?

Comment: @A G Yes! disable only input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enterButton` prop & provide a custom button component.

```
const { Search } = Input;

const customButton = <Button type="primary" icon={<SearchOutlined />} />;

const onSearch = (value) => console.log(value);

const App = () => (
  <Space direction="vertical">
    <Search
      placeholder="input search text"
      enterButton={customButton}
      disabled
      size="large"
      onSearch={onSearch}
    />
  </Space>
);
```

In the example, `input` is disabled but you can click the custom search button & see the console logs.

[image: Edit Search box - antd@4.21.2 (forked)]